# How to set working dir for Gradle task in Intellij?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

The IntelliJ Run/Debug configuration UI used to have a field for "Working dir". However, the UI seems to have changed in a recent version, and I can't find that field any more.

I've tried adding `--project-dir ../path` to the "Tasks and arguments" field, but that doesn't do anything.

How do I set the working dir for Gradle tasks?

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the project in **Gradle project** field of the run configuration:

[image]

Comment: That's just the project containing the task. I need to specify the *working dir*.

Comment: Project sets the working directory. What does not work with this option?

Comment: Check this discussion: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/change-gradle-working-directory-in-a-standard-operating-system-way-where-gradle-is-launched-and-not-where-the-build-gradle-is-located/7153